# CSS outline property is not working inside the handlebars. Why?

Tags: css, handlebars.js

I have a login form inside handlebars page and I want to set default outline property to none for that element. How to do that ?

### Code inside the handlebars file

```
<input type="text" class="form-control  w-25 mt-2  border-dark 
    rounded-0" name="Name" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                    placeholder="Enter Name" style="outline: none;" >
```

This is not removing the chrome's default blue outline when mouse clicks on.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then add this `box-shadow: none;`

Comment: It's working . But, I want to include the box shadow tooo.

Comment: Then you can change the color for this `.your_callss_name:focus {border-color: #80bdff; box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);}`

Comment: I don't think this question is about Handlebars. I think you should remove the handlebars.js tag and possibly add a bootstrap one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to code the following..

```
input[type="text"]{
outline:none;
}
```